# Close an activity forever

Tags: java, android

So I have a SignUp Activity and a MainActivity in the application. Once the User signs up, it redirects to the MainActivity. But when I exit it and open it again, the SignUp Activity appears again. What I want is that once the user signs up, the SignUp Activity never appears again when app is closed. See Facebook, once I register for it, the SignUp Activity never appears again. That's what I want in my application. I have tried `finish()` but it again appears when I clear it from background or click on back button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand you have your SignUp Activity as your Startup Activity. Then I see two potential solution for it:

**1) Using SharredPreferences:**
When user signs up store a boolean isSignedIn in a shared preference and then you can use that to check whether the user is signed in or not. If the user isSignedIn then simply start the MainActivity.

**2) Using AuthStateListener (Only if your using Firebase):**
Firebase provides with the authStateListener which lets you know when the authentication state changes.

Comment: Thanks @Cyborg. Figured it out. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **sharedpreferences**. Save the user id in the sharedpreferences, If you have a valid string in sharedpreferences then directly navigate to MainActivity. If not direct to SignUpActivity. Make the sharedpreferences value null if the user signs out.

Comment: but how? Give me a example of code